# Sonar Java Web Client: Authors by line null

Tags: java, web-services, sonarqube

When running the following code on my Sonar, measure returns null. (Should return something on the lines of "1=author;2=author..."). However it works on nemo.sonarsource.org.

Other measures eg: violation work correctly on mine so this is probably not a question of faulty code. I suspect I need to configure Sonar somehow?

```
    private final Sonar sonar;

    public String getAuthors(String resourceKey){
         return getMeasure(resourceKey, "authors_by_line").getData();
    }

    private Measure getMeasure(String resourceKey, String measureName){
        Resource resource = sonar.find(ResourceQuery.createForMetrics(
            resourceKey, measureName));

        Measure measure = resource.getMeasure(measureName);

        return measure;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have installed the [SCM Activity plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin) and enabled it (in Sonar settings, see the documentation on our Wiki) in order to be able to get this metric.

Then, once you have reanalysed your project, you'll get the expected behaviour.